# Japan rail travel individual tickets vs rail-pass

Tags: trains, tickets, japan

I'm going to be travelling from Kagoshima to Tokyo via Osaka with a stop-over in Osaka.

Which are the operator websites I will need to buy tickets with, and would this be the cheapest/best option or would it be better to get a rail-pass of some description?

Comment: Just to avoid repeating what you already know, what have you found so far and why doesn't it work for you ?

Comment: Rail is pretty much never the cheapest option for a single trip. Please clarify whether traveling by rail is a requirement for you, or you just say "rail" because it's the only thing you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.aoimirai.net/japan/jrpass_calculator.html
http://www.hyperdia.com/
Here, just calculate if it's worth to get a JR pass. 
If you traveling off-peak, just buy them at the counter.

Comment: To be more precise, you *can't* buy Japanese train tickets online without jumping through a whole lot of mostly Japanese-only hoops.